# How to serialise ember date?

Tags: serialization, ember.js

I'm new to ember and I want to post a new record, So I did something like:

```
App.AdminController = Em.Controller.extend
  submit: ->
    post = App.Post.createRecord()
    post.set('author', $('#author').val())
    post.set('title', $('#title').val())
    post.set('intro', $('#intro').val())
    post.set('description', $('#description').val())
    post.set('publishedAt', new Date())
    post.get('store').commit()
```

Everything works like a charm, except the `publisedAt` attribute e in `post` request json file is null

[image]

I think the problem is due to that I may not serialise it correctly, any idea?

---

update the model:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr('string')
  author: DS.attr('string')
  intro: DS.attr('string')
  description: DS.attr('string')
  publishedat:DS.attr('date')
```

Comment: Can you show your ember-data model for the above?

Answer (score 0):

Try using JSON.stringify on the Date object:

```
post.set('publishedAt', JSON.stringify(new Date()))
```

Comment: I've update the model, the data type for publisedAt is `date`, instead of string

Comment: No, it still is nil in the post body

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you can't invoke new Date() inside the .set method. This should work:

```
    var d = new Date();
    post.set('publishedAt', d);
```